# Continuous deployment for website into AWS S3 using Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bitbucket, bower

I have a static website written using frameworks AngularJS and Bootstrap CSS. All the framework dependencies are managed using [Bower](https://bower.io/).

Currently, I do `bower install` and then copy my site contents into an **AWS S3** bucket and publish it as a website. Every time I make a tiny change in any file, I delete all the contents of the bucket and upload the code (containing changes).

I am using Bitbucket as version control system.

I want to cut the process of doing `bower install` and manual upload, I'd rather deploy the website as soon as I push the code into Bitbucket. What can be done? I have no knowledge of Bitbucket pipelines.

Comment: https://www.savjee.be/2016/06/Deploying-website-to-ftp-or-amazon-s3-with-BitBucket-Pipelines/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script below worked for me. Step 1 installs bower dependencies, and step 2 deploy the changes to S3 bucket.

```
image: php:7.1.1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Install dependencies
        image: node:8.5.0
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm install -g bower
          - bower install --allow-root
        artifacts:
          - bower_components/**

    - step:
        # set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as environment variables
        name: Deploy to S3
        deployment: test   # set to test, staging or production
        # trigger: manual  # uncomment to have a manual step
        image: atlassian/pipelines-awscli
        script:
          - aws s3 sync --delete . s3://www.tarkshala.com
```